# Awk Bash If-Else Issue

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

I have a problem of being unable to printout a error message if 0 records are found.

this is what I have as of now.

```
function search_title
{
    awk -F':' -v search="$Title" '$2 ~ search { i++;} END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' test.txt
    awk -F':' -v search="$Title" '$2 ~ search { i++; printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END {}' test.txt
}

function search_author
{
    awk -F':' -v search="$Author" '$2 ~ search { i++;} END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' test.txt
    awk -F':' -v search="$Author" '$2 ~ search { i++; printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END {}' test.txt
}

function search_both
{
    awk -F':' -v search="$Title" -v search1="$Author" '$1 ~ search && $2 ~ search1 { i++;} END { printf "%d records found\n", i }' test.txt
    awk -F':' -v search="$Title" -v search1="$Author" '$1 ~ search && $2 ~ search1 { i++; printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 } END {}' test.txt
}

read -p $'Title: ' Title
read -p $'Author: ' Author

if [ "$Title" == "" ];
then
search_author
elif [ "$Author" == "" ];
then
search_title
else
search_both
fi
```

I need a if else statement to check if the counter is 0 in awk print out "Error! Book does not exist"

For example,
Title input as DAFT
Author input as Linken 
(Both value not in test.txt)

"Error! Book does not exist"
instead of the printf now which is "0 Record Found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 awk command in each function:

You can combine both awk in one command:

```
awk -F':' -v search="$Title" -v search1="$Author" '$1 ~ search && $2 ~ search1 {
         i++;
         printf "%s, %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5;
      }
      END {
          if (!i)
             print "Error! Book does not exists!";
          else 
             printf "%d records found\n", i;
      }' test.txt
```

Comment: Is it possible to retain the counter display for the cases where there are records?

such as 
if(i!=0)
//printf i record found
else//if i == 0
//error book does not exists

can this be done?

Comment: wow! thats an amazing way of using awk. thanks alot for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. awk is pretty powerful tool actually, you can replace all of you shell script code in awk.